# Why does my jQuery toggleClass not work properly within in my C# repeater?

Tags: c#, jquery, repeater

I have a c# application using a repeater and jQuery to add a little pizzaz to my application. The first portion of the jQuery functions correctly as the content slides up and down to hide or show whatever **ONE** section had been clicked on, but the second portion changes all classes including the one inside the section clicked. Why is this?

Here is my repeater layout:

```
<ItemTemplate>                    
        <div class="head"><span class="expand">&nbsp;</span> <%#Eval("Job_Title") %></div>
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px 0px 20px 50px; display: none;">
        <div><%#Eval("Status") %></div>
        <div><%#Eval("Department") %></div>
        <div><%#Eval("Posting_Site") %></div>
        <div><%#Eval("Job_Duties") %></div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.head').click(function () {
            $(this).next('div.row').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400, function () {
                $('.expand').toggleClass('collapse'); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.expand')` targets all elements with that class, if you just want to target the one inside the current `.head` you'd do

```
$(this).prev('.head').find('.expand').toggleClass('collapse')
```

or the opposite would be

```
var thisOne = $(this).prev('.head').find('.expand');

$('.expand').not(thisOne).toggleClass('collapse');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a class as your selector and then using next, means that you are iterating over each 'head' that contains 'div.row'.

You need to change it this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.head').click(function () {
        $('.head div.row').slideToggle(400, function () {
            $('.expand').toggleClass('collapse'); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, `div.row` is not a child of `.head`, it's the next element after `.head`, hence the use of `next()`

Comment: Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector. (http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: You nailed it, that's what it does, and `.row` is the immediately following sibling of `.head`, not it's child, so `$('.head div.row')` matches absolutely nothing.

Comment: When I use this neither the show/hide nor the image swap works